# gettext .mo file issue

Tags: php, encoding, localization

I've created a he_IL.po file, edited a simple `'Hello World'` entry and it works just fine (my server has all the locales, translation works...) the thing is that it is not showing non-latin chars (checked Hebrew/Chinese), I've added a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` yet still I don't see the correct chars. you can see the output sample at http://postimg.org/image/4zn4m107z/
It should say `Translated text with some עברית` (where עברית = hebrew)

This is my sample code:
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

```
    $locale = 'he_IL';

    setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
    bindtextdomain("messages",'./locale');
    textdomain("messages");
    echo gettext("Hello World");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say "try" in an answer, but gettext can be a bit fickle sometimes, so... try:

- `bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8')`, to tell gettext to use UTF-8
- `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL.UTF-8')`, or `he_IL.utf8` or whatever other variation is installed on your server; use `$ locale -a` on the command line to figure it out

Locales come in different encodings too, the default `he_IL` locale may not be UTF-8 in your case.

Comment: bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF-8') did the job ;-)